# How to automate a Siebel GUI?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, siebel

I'm looking for a way to automate a Siebel Retail 8.1 GUI (High Interactivity) for functional tests.

The only option I found so far is using QTP from HP, which is quite expensive.

Do you know any alternatives, or do you have any experiences with QTP?

Comment: It is probably due to the Active X controls still used in Siebel GUI in the HI Client. SI Client allows JQuery use, it's a good alternative meanwhile the release of Open UI layer. What are the main (open source) alternatives you talked about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTP is a great all-purpose test automation tool.  I do not know much about Siebel Retail 8.1 GUI - is it web-based or thick client?  If web-based, there are a ton of alternatives, including open source.  If it's a thick client, you are limited in your choices.  Vendor alternatives to QTP are IBM Rational Functional Tester, Compuware TestPartner, Borland SilkTest.

You might want to check out the related SO questions:

- Tools for automated GUI testing (on Windows)?
- Is there any way to automate windows forms testing?
- Automated testing of GUI
- Automated testing of Windows Forms

Comment: The Siebel GUI uses DHTML + Custom Active-X controls.

Comment: QTP is usually the best way to solve the problem, especially if you want to verify data in the Business layer.

Comment: Custom ActiveX controls might make it tricky for the open source solutions, in which case you might need to get a vendor solution, such as those I mentioned.

Comment: Finally we decided to use QTP. After installing the Siebel Test Automation Module, it works perfect for us.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ATS is the official tool to automate Siebel GUI.

There are 2 different Siebel GUI, one is the old HI/SI, which is activeX and need IE to view. 
another one is called OpenUI, which is pure web.

Oracle ATS both support them, following video at Oracle show how to test Siebel.

the first one is created by me. and the last two for load testing Siebel.

https://otube.oracle.com/media/Siebel+OpenUI+functional+testing+new+feature++in+OATS+13.1.0.1+by+Sophia+Du/0_eya24f4k/2902

https://otube.oracle.com/media/Siebel+load+testing+%28Part+IA+creating+load+script%29/0_2hlxkxa6/2902

https://otube.oracle.com/media/Siebel+Load+Testing+%28Part+IIA+How+to+Do+Performance+Testing+for+Siebel+OpenUI+Application%29+by+Anna+Huang/0_raccbegx/2902

Comment: BTW: Oracle Application Testing Suite is an Oracle commercial product for testing all kinds of Oracle applications including Siebel and I am working for this product.  see: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I know it's a late reply - but please don't put too much faith in QTP to test Siebel. Experience of myself and colleagues in the Siebel development community (yes, there is one :) have found considerable problems with the practicalities of using QTP to test Siebel.